# Make nearby pixels white opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image and I want to achieve the following -

If a pixel is white, make it's nearby 10x10 pixels white.

I know I can do it by using convolutions and a kernel, but are there any functions in opencv that can do this?

Comment: perform morphological operations (preferably dilation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better illustrate my comment here is an example.

This is the image:

[image]

Performing dilation using a kernel of size 5 x 5:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilation)
```

This is the result:

[image]